# Converting a script from rpy to rpy2 using rpy2.rpy_classic

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to python, but I want to convert a python script using rpy into one using rpy2. We do have rpy installed somewhere (for python 2.6.x), but it's not playing nicely with the current version of R (3.2.0). We do however have rpy2 installed for the version of python being used in these scripts (python 2.7[.5])

As far as I can tell, these are the lines which need to change (I've simplified the function a bit):

```
from rpy import r

r.library('<libname>', quietly=True)
r("""\
func <- function(x,a={options.a},b={options.b})  {{
... 
*R code here* 
...
l<-list(o=o,md=a+b) 
l
}}""".format(options=options))
```

and later in the script, there's a line which calls this function:

```
out = r.func(<python expression>)['o']
```

I can do the first half as follows:

```
import rpy2.rpy_classic as rpy

rpy.set_default_mode(rpy.NO_CONVERSION)

rpy.r.library('<libname>', quietly=True)
rpy.r("""\
func <- function(x,a={options.a},b={options.b})  {{
... 
*R code here* 
...
l<-list(o=o,md=a+b) 
l
}}""".format(options=options))
```

Trying the above at an interactive prompt (with some fake data), the output is:

```
<rpy2.rpy_classic.Robj object at 0x2b9e48481510>
```

but I need the output value of the function `rpy.r.func` rather than its not-converted value (as I need to obtain the `func(<expression)$o` value)

Am I moving on the right track? And how do I rewrite the rpy (v1) code so that I get what I want (from rpy2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rpy_classic` was mostly there in the early days to demonstrate that the lower-level interface in rpy2 could be used to implement any higher-level interface, including the one in `rpy`. It is not meant to be an ultimate compatibility tool.

With rpy2's high-level interface `robjects`, your rpy code would look like:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import r

lib=importr('<libname>')
rfunc=r("""
  function(x,a={options.a},b={options.b})  {{
    ... 
    *R code here* 
    ...
    l<-list(o=o,md=a+b) 
    l
  }}""".format(options=options))

out = rfunc(<python expression>).rx2('o')
```

Comment: I needed to add

 `import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri`
 `rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()`

as I'm passing a numpy object, but this did work